# EJB and FLEX

Tags: java, apache-flex, ejb-3.0, integration, blazeds

I'm working on a new application using EJB3 -> BlazeDS -> Flex.
I can't find good example to see how to integrate EJB with BLAZEDS. Can someone give me some pointers on how to link them together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BlazeDS is essentially a Tomcat server. Tomcat does not fully support J2EE, but it does support some JNDI. You can put EJB's into WEB-INF/web.xml and META-INF/context.xml

Here is Tomcat's documentation on using beans:[JNDI resources](http://www.mbaworld.com/docs/jndi-resources-howto.html)

EDIT: Found this for Glassfish -> BlazeDS -> Flex: [Flex-BlazeDS-and-GlassFish](http://anachronymous.com/2009/01/flex-blazeds-and-glassfish-part-1.html)

Comment: I'm using Glasfish server for my application. So, j2ee technology should work fine.